# How to truncate datetime seconds in Flask-SQLAlchemy SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a datetime column in my SQLite database that gets updated each time a user logs in. When I query the datetime values, I get loads of digits.

```
2020-12-30 09:46:15.846780
```

I'm not sure why this happens, in all the other places I've looked there are only three digits of milliseconds. Either way, how can I truncate the seconds and keep only the minutes and hours?

Here's my code in models.py:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ... other columns
    last_login_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    @classmethod
    def update_login_date(self):
         self.last_login_date = datetime.utcnow()
         db.session.commit()

@login_manager.user_loader
# def...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to care about the digits of time, you can format the date and time to whatever format you want with [`strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). For example, you can use it in the template like this:

```
{{ user.last_login_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
```

The format codes `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` will output something like `'2020-12-30 14:05:16'`. Check the list of all the available format codes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).